# Validity check of S4 class in R

Tags: r

I'm fairly new to R and even newer to S4 classes and encountered some problems with the validity check. Simply put, it's not working. Here my code:

```
check_filter_type <- function(object) {
    length_filter_type <- length(object@filter_type)
    #return("No filter type was specified.")
    if (length_filter_type == 0L) {
        return("No filter type was specified.")
    }
    possible_filter <- c('cutData', 'generateTimestamps', 
                         'loadRawData', 'insertEventEntry', 
                         'insertTimestampOffsetEntry', 
                         'insertOffsetCorrectedEventEntry')
    if(!(object@filter_type %in% possible_filter)) {
        return("An unknown filter type was requested.")
    }
    return(TRUE)
}

setClass(
    "filterPreProcessing", 
    representation(filter_type = "character"),
    validity=check_filter_type
)
```

Whatever character argument I pass as filter_type, the class gets created although it shouldn't as defined in my validity function.

```
filter <- new("filterPreProcessing", filter_type="")
validObject(filter)
#[1] TRUE

filter <- new("filterPreProcessing", filter_type="unknown")
validObject(filter)
#[1] TRUE
```

I'm pretty sure I misunderstand how it is supposed to work, but after looking through a number of tutorials and examples I can't pinpoint my mistake.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue; try restarting your R session and testing your code again.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to write initialize generic for your class. It won't police the class if you decide to edit slots though (see below).

```
setMethod('initialize', 'filterPreProcessing', 
          function(.Object, filter_type) {
  .Object@filter_type <- filter_type
  validObject(.Object)
  return(.Object)
})
```

You should write a generic to access and edit the slots in your class.

```
setGeneric('filter_type', function(object) standardGeneric('filter_type'))
setMethod('filter_type', 'filterPreProcessing', function(object) {
  return(object@filter_type)
})
setGeneric('filter_type<-', function(object) standardGeneric('filter_type<-'))
setMethod('filter_type<-', 'filterPreProcessing', 
          function(object, new_filter_type) {
  object@filter_type <- new_filter_type
  validObject(object)
  return(object)
})
```

Take this with a grain of salt. Someone else ought to come along and give a better answer.